# What could be the possible method to check if the current time is after the expirationTime?

Tags: reactjs, dayjs

I am currently working on checking the validity of my otp.

Using DayJs as my library for providing time, I came up with this function.

What i wanted is to check if expiration time isAfter the current system time in order to check the otp's validity.

I already tried using isBefore and also get false. Since it always return false, what could be my possible mistake?

```
 const [otpResult, setOtpResult] = useState("CEIT");
  
  let otp = "";
  let startTime;
  let expirationTime;

  const generateOtp = (length, id) => {
    var characters =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    var charactersLength = characters.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length + 1; i++) {
      otp += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    console.log("the otp is: " + otp);
    setOtpResult(otp);
    startTime = dayjs().format("HH:mm:ss");
    expirationTime = dayjs().add(10, "m").format("HH:mm:ss");

    let isValid = dayjs(expirationTime).isAfter(dayjs(startTime));
    console.log(isValid);
  };
```

Comment: please include the code in the question without using an image

Comment: instead of comparing formated string you need to compare date objects. e.g. `dayjs().add(10, "m").isAfter(dayjs())`

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is `startTime` and `expirationTime` are 'time strings'.

So when you are creating a dayjs object, you need to specify a parse format.

Refer: https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/string-format

or just compare the dayjs objects.

```js
const dayjs = require("dayjs")
const startTime = dayjs();
const expirationTime = dayjs().add(10, "m");

let isValid = expirationTime.isAfter(startTime);
console.log(startTime);
console.log(expirationTime);
console.log(isValid); // true
```